# Keyboard got crazy after pluging in ipod

Tags: ipod, apple, numpad

asus x550L, ubuntu 14.04 and old ipod

I plugged it in to charge it, I couldn't close the folder and system behaved like 1 on the num keyboard is pressed. It turns on automatically every minute, also left ctrl does the same, imagine yourself how writing this looks like with such a mess, please help..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rebooting didn't help of course, after plugging in ipod again I had my first Linux crash, it just stopped responding besides the mouse.

Switching into windows and going back to linux was for the first time in the history a solution, not the cause of a problem :)

Never buy apple.